# displaying recent keystrokes in emacs

Tags: emacs

How do I recover the most recent keystrokes I just typed in Emacs?  I'm a long-time Emacs user (30 years), but every so often I mistype a key sequence, something strange happens, and I want to know what sequence of chars I typed, compared with what I thought I typed.  I know there's a command that shows a couple dozen of the most recent chars I typed, but I can't remember what it is, and I can't seem to find it either.  For example, sometimes in `dired-mode`, I move the cursor to a file, and I type `!` to run a command on that file, but I type some other sequence by mistake, and suddenly I see I've selected all files in the `dired` buffer—all files are marked with `*`.  I'm trying to debug my typing in this situation.

Comment: C-h l is the best solution. Other solution, would be to  define new keybindings, when this happens to avoid mistyping.

Comment: +1: Indeed, the `view-lossage` Elisp function name is *NOT* an intuitive function name that is easy to remember. In my searches the closest I could find is `recent-keys` which has not a user-friendly output as does `view-lossage`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>l</kbd>, which invokes `view-lossage`.

Comment: Is it possible to dynamically update `view-lossage` ?

Answer (score 8):

Use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `view-lossage` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

> view-lossage is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `help.el'. It
>   is bound to <kbd>C-h l</kbd>, <kbd><f1> l</kbd>, <kbd><help> l</kbd>.
>
> (view-lossage)
>
> Display last 300 input keystrokes.